# How to get started with bitcoin-cli on macOS?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, mac

I've been having a really hard time struggling through installation. The problem is there seem to be two ways to install, one through a [download link](https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-24.0.1/) and one through src. However, both methods still have many problems and the dependencies are unclear. I explained the specifics of the problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/26778).

I was hoping that I would be able to download [bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) from GitHub, enter the [src](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src) file, and run `./bitcoind` or `./bitcoin-qt -server` to be able to run in prune mode. However, I am still getting errors. For example,

IN:

```
./bitcoin-qt -server
```

OUT:

```
zsh: killed     ./bitcoin-qt -server
```

I am not able to download the whole blockchain at 500 GB, but I need to use the `bitcoin-cli`. My thought was running `./bitcoin-qt -server` would allow me to prune the download as explained on [StackExchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13368/whats-the-difference-between-bitcoind-and-bitcoin-qt-different-commands) and operate `bitcoin-cli`, without having to run `bitcoind` first.

**Questions**

1. Is running `bitcoind` necessary to run `bitcoin-cli`?
2. Is it possible to run `bitcoin-cli` without downloading the entire
   blockchain?
3. What is the cleanest path to getting started with `bitcoin-cli` on macOS?

Answer (score 2):

> Is running bitcoind necessary to run bitcoin-cli?

No, you can use bitcoin-cli with bitcoin-qt but you must first tell bitcoin-qt to listen for requests from blitcoin-cli - it does not do this by default.

```
$ ./bitcoin-qt -server &
```

See https://livebook.manning.com/book/grokking-bitcoin/a-using-bitcoin-cli/v-6/34

---

```
zsh: killed     ./bitcoin-qt -server
```

You probably need to reinstall homebrew.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119081/why-does-zsh-kills-my-process-every-time-i-enter-a-git-command

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think your proposed solution moves things in the right direction, but unfortunately the problem persists. I am no getting new error readout.