# bitcoind won't run on macos

Tags: bitcoind, mac

I have downloaded the tgz file from bitcoincore.org and unpacked it. The first time I tried to run bitcoind from the command line, I got the usual macOS dialog about untrusted software, so I gave the necessary permission in System settings. However, when I tried to run it again, all I get is `zsh: killed     bin/bitcoind`. I've tried `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get started with bitcoin-cli on macOS?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116628/how-to-get-started-with-bitcoin-cli-on-macos)

Comment: the solution seems to be to install homebrew, which I already have. I also checked for crash reports in macos Console, but there is nothing relevant. So I guess it's a different issue maybe? I wish there was some way to get more error output at least. "killed" is not really something you can google..

Comment: P.S.: Just to be on the safe side I reinstalled brew, but that didn't change anything

Comment: Maybe related: https://bisq.wiki/Downloading_and_installing#macOS, but really a blind guess, i don't know nothing about MacOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out after some googling: On ARM, macOS refuses to run any binary that isn't signed, and the ones in the tgz download obviously aren't:

```
codesign -d -vvv --entitlements :- bin/bitcoind
bin/bitcoind: code object is not signed at all
```

So I created a certificate and signed the binary as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27474942/2792352

Now `bitcoind` runs. I feel like that requirement should really be documented somewhere, but maybe I just missed it..

Answer (score 3):

since the binaries are not signed, macOS prevents their execution

how to check:

```
$ codesign -v -d bitcoin-qt
bitcoin-qt: code object is not signed at all
```

Self-sign as follows and you are good to go:

```
$ codesign -s - ./releases/v24.0.1/bin/bitcoind
```

this was mentioned here:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/26778#issuecomment-1368892763