# Why does bitcoind store block data in a different directory than bitcoin-qt does?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-qt-setup

I downloaded the bitcoin blockchain with

```
./bitcoin-qt
```

When I first executed the command I could tell him to use a mounted hard drive. All the data goes there. So far so good.
Now I want to experiment also with

```
./bitcoind
```

With bitcoind its running through all blocks one by one and gives me updateTip: new best, height, version, log2_work, tx, date, progress and cache. And when I execute the command

```
df
```

all the data goes on the SD-card and not on the hard drive.
What is the bitcoind doing there and how can I tell it to use the hard drive and not the SD-Card? Because there is not much space left

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may answer your question: [What's the difference between bitcoind and bitcoin-qt? Different commands?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/13369/87158)

Comment: Not really an answer to my question what is happening even though I downloaded the blockchain already. Don’t know where the data is stored when executing bitcoind (its not the blockchain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide the same path to `bitcoind` as you did for `bitcoin-qt`. Let's say you gave `/path/to/data` to `bitcoin-qt`, you should start `bitcoind` with `./bitcoin -datadir=/path/to/data`. Otherwise it will download all blocks in the default dir (On Linux is `~/.bitcoin`)